# Error Handling onFailure in retrofit2 (reasons)

Tags: java, retrofit2

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

when request timeout t.getMessage() is null.

i want catch exception on onFailure(Throwable t) to show like :

- no internet connection;
- request timeout;
- internal error!;
- Invalid credentials;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `Throwable` has a message and if not skip to a default message:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    String message = t.getMessage() != null ? t.getMessage() : "An error occurred!";
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I added the same code to onFailure. When the Internet is down, it: "Unable to resolve host "(domen)": No addr..." Even if I type in a non-existent domain, I get the same message as I said before, and after a long wait, the same message appears. I would like to toast about the internet if there is a problem with the internet. Notify the domain if there is a problem with the domain.